# How to simulate keypress with a button click on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am currently working on a calculator and wondered if there is a way to link keypresses to buttons so when I click a button, it simuliates the key being pressed and sends that info to the textbox.

When I google, all the info I get is enabling buttons by keypresses but not the other way around.

If someone could help me cause my code is already a mess with all the conversations and keypress events.

Comment: You can use jQuery - `keydown(function(e) => { ... }` and there you can specify `e.keyCode == 32` as `32` is for space bar. Get key code from here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Comment: why are you not just adding a space to the input directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is answered in this Stackoverflow thread: [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically).

To add it to the textbox you can listen to the keydown event and add the character accordingly.